# 'LOG_INFO' macro redefined warning after moved project to swift bridging project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, objective-c-swift-bridge, cocoalumberjack

I got several warnings like these:

```
Swift compiler warning:
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

/Myfolder/Pods/Headers/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h:176:9: 'LOG_INFO' macro redefined
/Myfolder/Pods/Headers/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h:177:9: 'LOG_DEBUG' macro redefined
```

The warning complains about DDLog.h in the Projet-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDASLLogger.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Swift automatically imports `syslog.h`, which defines constants with the same name.

If your Swift code doesn't need the syslog constants, you should be able to undefine them before importing `DDLog.h` to get rid of the warning.

```
#undef LOG_INFO
#undef LOG_DEBUG
#import "DDlog.h"
```